# how to reduce the number of sudo-io inodes with tar linux command?

Tags: bash, tar, subdirectory, inode

After patching I am trying to reduce inodes at `/var` directory due the sudoer activity logging. I use  `tar` command for archiving the subfolders into 1 file by below command but failing to untar the folder during testing.

The command what already have tried:

```
for i in $(ls -d /var/log/sudo-io/*); do tar -cvJf $i.xz /var/log/sudo-io ; <rm -rf $i; > done
```

I would like to except only xz files at `sudo-io` folder, and archiving subfolders by automated bash command (cron, ...) to reduce the number of inodes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, `for i in /var/log/sudo-i/*; do` is _much_ less buggy than injecting `ls` into there. See [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: What's with the `<` and `>` in `<rm -rf $i; >`? `<rm` tries to redirect stdin from a file named `rm` while running the command `-rf` (which doesn't exist)

Comment: ...as for skipping `.xz` files, think about `[[ $i = *.xz ]] && continue` before the `tar`.

Comment: For why you Never use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see also [Bash Pitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) -- there is a reason that is #1...